# LINQ query works in LINQPad but in C#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-2.2

Below `LINQ` query works as expected in `LINQPad` but when I use this in Web API, it returns `Nullable object must have a value` exception.

Here is my code.

```
        var GRStk = (from g in GRStkB4
              join t1 in opTOs on g.itemCode equals t1.itemCode into temp1
              from op in temp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                   g.branchCode,
                   g.itemCode,
                   qty = g.availQty - op.opqty
               }).AsEnumerable().Where(w => w.qty > 0); // exception

       int ii = GRStk.Count(); // Exception with Nullable object must have a value.
```

I use `Asp.Net Core 2.2`
I could not understand how it works in LINQPad and what is nullable here?

Comment: Try following :int? ii = GRStk.Count();  Add the question mark to accept null values.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: before int ii = GRStk.Count(); itself query returns exception. for question purpose i used this line, in fact, i would use foreach on GRStk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some commands in your query being evaluated in the client side when using EF, but not in linqPad. i.e if op is null then you may not be able to access op.opqty if it is evaluated in the client-side.

I guess changing the following line will solve your problem tho:

```
...
                        select new
              {
                   g.branchCode,
                   g.itemCode,
                   qty = g.availQty - (op!= null ?  op.opqty : 0) //edit here!
               }).AsEnumerable().Where(w => w.qty > 0); // exception exception
...
```

Comment: qty is decimal so error is "operator ?? cannot be applied to decimal and decimal. when i add (w.qty ?? (decimal)0) > 0

Comment: @Ramesh I edited my answer. I hope you understand the point here. You need to check whether op is null.